# Are barebone computers just a motherboard and case?

Tags: motherboard

Are barebone computers, like the ones sold on newegg just a case and a motherboard?

You just add the drives,hdd, and memory??

For example:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856101077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, yes. They also include the processor heatsink/cooler that fits the chassis if the chassis requires a non-standard one.

You want to check the description and specifications to make sure what you get as there is no set standard.

Comment: Most barebones actually don't include a cpu or cooler. Some, like shuttle, will include a cooler if a standard form factor cooler will not fit.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. I'll update the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard has integrated audio, video, LAN.

Buy a harddisk, cdrom, memory and CPU then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd need to add a number of components.  The linked configuration includes a case and motherboard, but the motherboard happens to have on-board audio, an on-board network adapter, and an on-board video adapter.  This means you'd not only need to add hard drives, DVD drives, and memory, but you'd even need to add your own CPU.  (Note the usage of the term "CPU supported.")